# Google dual y chart lines overlap

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

While using google dual y line chart, one problem appeared - when both y lines have same trend, they tend to overlap which hides one of the lines. Is there any solution for this?

example data:

```
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2014, 0),     1,  10],
    [new Date(2014, 1),   2,  20],
    [new Date(2014, 2),   4,  40],
    [new Date(2014, 3),     8,  80],
    [new Date(2014, 4),  16,    160],
    [new Date(2014, 5),  32,  320],
    [new Date(2014, 6),  64,  640],
    [new Date(2014, 7), 128, 1280],
    [new Date(2014, 8), 256, 2560],
    [new Date(2014, 9), 512, 5120],
    [new Date(2014, 10),1024,10240],
    [new Date(2014, 11), 2048,  20480]
  ]);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxq1ykfw/

Comment: can you please share the code that you have tried ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil What exactly do you want? options? data?

Comment: need a sample of your code that you have tried. because its difficult to configure what exactly you want to do !

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil I made this fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/gxq1ykfw/